# Create dynamic filter in laravel using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, filtering

I trying to create a filter function inside a home page that will reload the product display section without refreshing the whole page by using jquery ajax. The logic is simple: use a controller to handle the logic which is expected to return a filtered array called `products`. Then pass this array to view to be displayed using `@foreach`. I also have a set of buttons to determine the category for filtering by take the button's value throught `request` parameter (which also doesn't work). I'm kinda stuck right now and don't know how to solve this problem. Hope you guys can provide me some idea and solutions.

Here is my code (I were trying to return an json but i don't know what to do next to display via the loop)

**Controller:**

```
public function getProductByCategory(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){

            $choosen_cate = $request->apply_filter //idk why this always null;

            $categoryId = ProductCategory::where('name', $choosen_cate)->value('id');
            $products = Product::where('category_id', $categoryId)->get();

            //dd($products);

            $categories = ProductCategory::all();

            return response()->json(['product' => $products]);
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="flex gap-2 text-center mt-5">
    <div class="w-1/5 flex flex-col gap-3">
        <form id="filter_form" action="{{route('product.filter.post')}}" method="POST" class="shadow-lg bg-slate-200 rounded-xl w-full h-fit px-2 pb-2 flex flex-col gap-2 items-center">
            @csrf
            <p class="uppercase font-bold text-xl mt-2">Danh mục</p>
            <div class="bg-white w-fit px-2 rounded-full">
                <input class="text-sm p-1 bg-transparent focus:outline-none" type="text" placeholder="Tìm kiếm danh mục">
                <i class="fa-solid text-sm fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
            </div>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <button value="{{$category->name}}" name="apply_filter" type="submit" class="flex justify-between capitalize text-slate-600 font-semibold text-start gap-1 w-full mx-2 p-1 rounded-lg hover: hover:bg-slate-300">
                    {{$category->name}}
                </button>
            @endforeach
        </form>
        <div class="shadow-lg bg-slate-200 rounded-xl w-full h-fit px-2 pb-2 flex flex-col items-center">
            Price Filter
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product_gallery" class="w-full bg-gradient-to-r from-[#0066C1] to-cyan-500 rounded-md">
        <div class="mx-12 my-3 text-start text-slate-100 text-lg uppercase font-semibold">
            Home >>
            @if(isset($cate))
            <span class="capitalize">{{$cate}}</span>
            @else
                <span class="capitalize">All</span>
            @endif
        </div>
        @if(count($products) == 0)
            <div class="shadow-xl flex justify-center items-center product-wrapper min-h-[724px] bg-white mx-12 p-3 gap-3 mb-10 rounded-lg">
                <p class="uppercase text-slate-300 font-semibold">There aren't any available products currently</p>
            </div>
        @else
            <div id="product_gallery" class="shadow-xl product-wrapper min-h-[724px] bg-white mx-12 grid grid-cols-4 justify-items-center p-3 gap-3 mb-10 rounded-lg">
                @foreach($products as $product)
                    <div class="product-card w-fit bg-white h-fit flex flex-col shadow-xl rounded-lg">
                        <a href="{{url('product_detail', $product->id)}}"><img class="w-60 h-60" src="{{$product->image}}"></a>
                        <p class="uppercase font-semibold text-center">{{$product->name}}</p>
                        <p class="text-[#1998EC] font-bold text-xl">{{$product->price}} $</p>
                        <p class="text-slate-400 text-xs line-through">1000.000$</p>
                        <div class="flex flex-row justify-between text-sm px-2 mb-2">
                            <div>
                                <p class="text-[#0DB866] font-semibold">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-square-check"></i>
                                    Còn hàng
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-slate-400">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-gift"></i>
                                    Quà tặng
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <form action="{{url('add_cart', $product->id)}}" method="POST" class="">
                                    @csrf
                                    <button class="h-full bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-blue-300 rounded-full text-white px-5"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#filter_form').submit(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('product.filter.post')}}",
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log('Error', error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/', [HomeManager::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::post('/', [HomeManager::class, 'getProductByCategory'])->name('product.filter.post');
```

Comment: I don't think you can alter what is used in the loop (I don't think the blade sees that you've updated the `$categories` and `$products` variable). I think you have to show the new products and categories using Javascript / Jquery.

Comment: do you have any document how to do and create such things, i've try to research but haven seen anything useful.

Comment: @GiaKhánh what you want to achieve is better done by livewire, htmx or any other frontend framework.

Comment: just use AlpineJS, use [for directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for), then bind your data using ajax or fetch call

Comment: While both Kris and Silver are correct, you should be able to implement something custom for it, should you not want to use Livewire or Alpine. The jist of a custom solution would be getting the filtered products and categories through an AJAX call in your javascript and then looping over them creating correct element for each product.

Comment: wow thanks you guys, i'm sure will try your recommendations :D